# How to startup FreeBSD in console mode

Tags: freebsd, console

I have recently installed a VMware image of FreeBSD, although when I boot up I get the message: Welcome to DesktopBSD, select from the following options:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNVOb.gif]

The trouble is when selecting options 1 - 4 I get the GUI and am unable to login as root, as its disabled in these modes.

How can I effectively exit and go into console mode, so I can login as root?

Answer (score 9):

You can try to switch from GUI to any other vty with `Alt+Ctrl+F1`. FreeBSD usually have X running on 9th console, so first 8 works in text mode.

Answer (score 4):

In an environment where the boot routine **did not offer the customary option to boot to console** – and where things such as <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> were ineffective …

### /etc/ttys

I experimented with making a comment of the line for ttyv8. So for example:

```
# Virtual terminals
ttyv1   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
ttyv2   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
ttyv3   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
ttyv4   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
ttyv5   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
ttyv6   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
ttyv7   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
# ttyv8   "/usr/local/bin/xdm -nodaemon"  xterm   off secure
```

That did not have the desired effect …

---

### PC-BSD

```
[gjp4@cces3-gjp4-pc-bsd-ergovista621] ~% cat /etc/rc.conf.pcbsd | grep -i pcdm
  # Enable the pcdm display manager
  pcdm_enable="YES"
[gjp4@cces3-gjp4-pc-bsd-ergovista621] ~%
```

– changing the *YES* to *NO* was effective.

---

### FreeBSD

If there's a display management line in `/etc/rc.conf` you can make a comment of it, e.g.

```
# kdm4_enable="YES"
```

– or change the *YES* to *NO*.

Comment: GhostBSD: `slim_enable="NO"` in `/etc/rc.conf`

Answer (score 1):

The Image shown is the bootloader.

Normally 4 should get you to single user mode.

Another option would bee selecting 6 and then type boot -s